# What is the difference between moderation and adjustment

Tags: regression, spss, interaction

What is the difference between moderation and adjustment in regression analysis? How can I conduct each of them in SPSS? I would appreciate any type of help.

Thanks..

Comment: I suggest adding the tag "spss" to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie but moderation means interaction so add an interaction.
To adjust add the variable with no interaction.

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/webbooks/reg/chapter6/regressionwith-spsschapter-6-more-on-interactions-of-categorical-variablesdraft-version/